# Java: How to find all "entry pairs with maximum value" from a Hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable, max

I want to find all "entry pairs with maximum value" from a Hashtable, my Hashtable is like this --

```
    Hashtable<Integer, Integer> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
    ht.put(1, 4);
    ht.put(2, 2);
    ht.put(3, 4);
    ht.put(4, 2);
    ht.put(5, 4);
```

I want to find these key-value pairs: `<1,4>, <3,4>, <5,4>`, I understand it could be done by finding the maximum valued entry first, then reiterate through the Hashtable to find other similar entries. But I was wondering if there is any elegant/simpler way to do this.

any idea ?

Comment: A hashtable is the wrong structure for that.  Create a class that ties two ints together, and then use sort a collection of those with a custom comparator (that is just x.a + a.b < y.a + y.b).

Comment: @Corbin: thanks for the suggestion, but I do not want to create a new class or subclassing Hashtable for this purpose. I was looking for a simple stand-alone procedure.

Comment: As you put the key:value pairs in the hash compare them to a highx and highy field.  If the x or y are higher then put the key in an array.  Iterate through the array to pull your pairs from the hash.  That is how I think I would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    final List< Entry< Integer, Integer > > maxList =
            new ArrayList< Entry< Integer, Integer > >();

    for ( final Entry< Integer, Integer > entry : ht.entrySet() ) {
        if ( max < entry.getValue() ) { 
            max = entry.getValue();
            maxList.clear();
        }
        if ( max == entry.getValue() )
            maxList.add( entry );
    }
```

Comment: Meh. Pretty much exactly the same as mine ;)

Comment: @Alex  And his was 11 minutes earlier, too.  :P

Comment: Yes, I kinda agree. But difference is that this is a complete, working algorithm and ramgorur wanted to collect the max pairs, not just the keys...

Comment: @CPerkina His was befor mine? Must've missed it

Comment: @icza Well the keys are in my list, and the values are all just currentMax... but whatever :)

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using some of the iteration patterns in [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
MutableMap<Integer, Integer> map = UnifiedMap.newWithKeysValues(1, 4)
    .withKeyValue(2, 2)
    .withKeyValue(3, 4)
    .withKeyValue(4, 2)
    .withKeyValue(5, 4);

Integer maxValue = map.valuesView().max();
RichIterable<Pair<Integer,Integer>> pairs =
    map.keyValuesView().select(
        Predicates.attributeEqual(Functions.<Integer>secondOfPair(), maxValue));

Assert.assertEquals(
    HashBag.newBagWith(Tuples.pair(1, 4), Tuples.pair(3, 4), Tuples.pair(5, 4)),
    pairs.toBag());
```

If you just need the keys from each pair, you can collect them.

```
RichIterable<Integer> maxKeys = pairs.collect(Functions.<Integer>firstOfPair());
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> keysForMaximums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    int key = /*get key from iterator*/;
    int val = /*get value from iterator*/;
    if(val > currentMax) {
        currentMax = val;
        keysForMaximums.clear();
    }
    if(val == currentMax)
        keysForMaximums.add(key);
}
```

Then keysForMaximum will be a list of the keys which contain the maximum value found in the map

What this does it it makes an empty list of Integers, and a number representing the maximum number found (defaults to lowest int value), then it goes through the map and checks if this guys has a bigger max, clear the list and set him to the biggest max, then if he is the biggest max add his key

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, hashtables are not used these days.
I would use a HashMap (it's also a KeyValue-List).

You can iterate your complete map with

```
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {  
    //  Your stuff here  
}
```

With this method you are getting the values and the keys.
For more information see [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29).

Best regards

Comment: As I am not worried about synchronization, choice of HashMap or Hashtable is not an issue here, moreover this "Map.Entry" gizmo could also be used with Hashtable -- and above all, your answer seems to be hardly related to my question. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: My first thought was, that you need entries with a specific value. With the Map.Entry gizmo you can also get the key of this entry. However, someone posted already a complete snippet. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by value and then search backwards until you get to a value that is != the last one.

But I like your approach, too. It's of linear complexity, i.e. ok for most usecases.